# replace image on ImageButton

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I'm new to andorid, and I'm trying to do a simple thing:
when button A is clicked, I want to replace the image displayed
on ImageButton B.

I've tried all sort of things like:

```
msortByButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                //Test change image         
                mdefineLocationButton.setBackgroundResource(0);
                mdefineLocationButton.invalidate();
                mdefineLocationButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notdefined);
                mdefineLocationButton.invalidate();             
                mdefineLocationButton.refreshDrawableState();
            }
        });
```

But it seems that the new image is painted, but on top of it the old image 
is painted also. (I can see the old image, below it I can see edges of the new image).

Any idea how to do this right?

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setImageResource (int resId)`

(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))

ImageButtons can have a background and an actual image src. My guess is initially you set the image src and now in code you are setting the background. So both show.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {                   
    mdefineLocationButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.notdefined);
}
```